# How can I create a copper coil texture in Blender?

Tags: texturing, materials, shaders, shader-nodes

I want to create a realistic-looking [stator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stator) in Blender, but I don't have any idea how to create the texture. I didn’t find one either.

[image]

This is the coil look I aim to achieve, and below is what I currently have

[image]

Comment: Hello, what is the shape of the copper object, is it a torus?

Comment: yes, it is a torus

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't need it to be as realistic as in your picture, you could plug a *Wave Texture* into a *Bump* node. Also use the UV output of the *Texture Coordinate* and use the *Mapping* node rotation value to tilt the waves. To make the texture joint correctly, scale precisely with the *Value* node:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very very much, exactly what I was looking for! :)

Comment: I guess some annoying busybody or other is going to come along and tell you that you [could have rotated the UV in the mapping node](https://imgur.com/a/uurzocB)

Comment: oh sure yes  ;)  .....

Answer (score 7):

### Geometric solution

If you're interested in a single render or baking the texture, you can make a honeycomb of bezier circles:

[image]

Make another circle, change handle types to free, in spline settings disable *Cyclic*, duplicate a vertex on one end of the "C" shape, select another end and press <kbd>F</kbd> to connect them. Now just set the vertices twist to $0$, $90°$, $180°$, $270°$ and $360°$ (for this honeycomb any multiple of $360°$ will do, but you could design a honeycomb with radial symmetry for e.g. $90°$ increments, or maybe as low as $30°$?)

Set the Object Bevel to the honeycomb curve (brace for performance impact):

[image]

Comment: Probably you could remove many circles inside the honeycomb...

Comment: Very nice! This even creates the irregularity caused by the winding. +1 ...and yes, a few wires could be saved here ;-)